# Swift aggressive optimization

Tags: swift, compilation, compiler-optimization

During reading the book:

> The swift programing language

In section **Nonescaping**. There is a column about aggressive optimization with `@noesacpe`. But explaining about what they mean using this "aggressive optimization" words is missing. Could you please explain what aggressive optimization is ?

Comment: This is a general term in the subject of compiler optimizations, and not specific to the Swift compiler. You can probably find numerous sources on examples of aggressive optimization via Google. Generally, I believe a language without side effect is suitable for allowing aggressive optimizations, whereas one with side effects might results in non-intended behaviour when using such optimization methods.

Comment: Thx for the response

Comment: @dfri post youre answer pls so i can accept

Comment: I don't believe my comment is sufficient for an answer, so I'll just leave it as it is above. Consider tagging your question `compilation` or `compiler-optimization` and possibly someone can give you a more complete answer (e.g. official sources).